# Как можно применить Алгоритм Лемпеля-Зи ва-Велча (Lempel-Ziv-Welch, LZW) для сжатия изображений?

Tags: алгоритм, изображения, сжатие

Собственно, в этом и состоит вопрос. Только начал разбираться с этим алгоритмом. На [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/116697/) или в [этом](http://www.e-postulat.ru%20%E2%80%BA%20index.php%20%E2%80%BA%20Postulat%20%E2%80%BA%20article%20%E2%80%BA%20download)  материале (вторая ссылка на скачивание) разбирают только сжатие и восстановление строк с абра-кадаброй. Мне не понятно, как с помощью этого алгоритма можно сжать изображение. Если с текстом, все более менее ясно (на уровне алгоритма),  начальный словарь в этом случае представляет собой расширенную ASCII таблицу, а расшифровать код потом относительно легко, то в случае картинки, как понять, где, например, координата пиксиля, а где его цвет? Может кто поделится ссылками на эту тему?

Comment: Зачем вам координаты? Просто берёте последовательно все пикселы картинки - и жмёте как одну большую последовательность чисел. Только отдельно наверное надо брать по очереди компоненты RGB. Ну то есть сначала R по всей картинке пакуете, потом G, потом B. В простейшем случае это будут числа от 0 до 255.

Comment: Но вообще я бы не рекомендовал использовать LZW - он во-первых довольно медленный, а во-вторых для картинок лучше работают алгоритмы, которые учитывают двумерную структуру рисунка, а не рассматривают его как один последовательный ряд пикселов.

Comment: Вторая ссылка, кстати, пустая